# How do I define and reference multi-dimensional arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I have a global definition in my controller for a multi-dimensional array as follows:

```
def ch
  @ch = Array.new(1){[]}
  @ch[0][0] = "Option 1"
  @ch[0][1] = "Option 2"
end
```

(I'm not sure if this is the best to do the array but I found an example online to do it this way)

in my controller action called "test", I am not able to print the values of the array appropriately.

```
def test
  logger.debug ch
  logger.debug ch[0]
  logger.debug ch[1]
  logger.debug ch[0][0]
  logger.debug ch[0][1]
end
```

stdout shows the following for the 5 logger statements respectively

```
Option 2
79
112
1
1
```

Why do the integers show? Any idea how I get the array values Option 1 and Option 2 to show?

If I define the array in the action itself (not doing it globally outside the action), I get the expected results i.e. `ch[0][0]` shows Option 1 and `ch[0][1]` shows Option 2. Eventually, I want to have access to the array in my view. There may be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.

1. In Ruby, the last line of a method is that method's return value; so the return value of `ch` is `"Option 2"`. Let's verify this on IRB, the Ruby REPL:

   ```
   [BinaryMuse ~]: irb
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > def ch
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002?>   ary = Array.new(1){[]}
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 :003?>   ary[0][0] = "Option 1"
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 :004?>   ary[0][1] = "Option 2"
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 :005?>   end
    => nil 
   ruby-1.9.2-p136 :006 > ch
    => "Option 2"
   ```
2. In `test`, you are calling the `ch` method rather than referencing the `@ch` variable. `logger.debug ch` is thus equivalent to `logger.debug "Option 2"`, and thus `ch[0]` is the first character of "Option 2", which is "O", which has the ASCII code 79. The same goes for `ch[1]`, which is "p", with the ASCII code 112. `ch[0][0]` returns the least significant bit of 79, which is 1, and so on.
3. Even if you change `test` to use `@ch` instead of calling the `ch` method, `@ch` still isn't defined since you haven't yet called `ch` to set up the `@ch` variable during your request. You can do this via a `before_filter` in your controller:

   ```
   class WhateverController
     before_filter :ch

     def ch
       # your code
     end

     def test
       logger.deubg @ch
       # etc.
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing methods and variables. When you do

```
def ch
...
end
```

you're defining a method and that method returns the last thing that was evaluated in it. In this case, the last thing you did in the method is:

```
@ch[0][1] = "Option 2"
```

which evaluates to `"Option 2"`. Therefore, when you call your method `ch` it will return `"Option 2"`. That's why

```
logger.debug ch
```

logs `"Option 2"`.

Now, *inside* your method `ch` you're creating an instance variable `@ch`. To log the values the way you wanted to, you would have to change your logging code like this:

```
logger.debug @ch
logger.debug @ch[0]
logger.debug @ch[1]
logger.debug @ch[0][0]
logger.debug @ch[0][1]
```

But, for this to work, you have to ensure that the code which creates the `@ch` instance variable has been executed before executing the `test` method. One way to do this is by having your `ch` method called using `before_filter`:

```
class YourControllerClassName
  before_filter :ch
```

Answer (score 2):

*Why do the integers show?*

Because the `ch` method return a "Option 2" string and calling the [] method on a string will return the integer value (ASCII code) of the letter at the index you wanted to get (i.e. ch[1] returns the int value of the "p" character).

*Any idea how I get the array values Option 1 and Option 2 to show?*

Define the ch method as:

```
def ch
  ch = Array.new(1){[]}
  ch[0][0] = "Option 1"
  ch[0][1] = "Option 2"
  return ch
end
```

Or leave it as is and modivie the test method:

```
def test
  ch # initialize the @ch instance variable
  logger.debug @ch
  logger.debug @ch[0]
  logger.debug @ch[1]
  logger.debug @ch[0][0]
  logger.debug @ch[0][1]
end
```

I think this will be helpful.
Cheers.